# Most Pythonic way to convert tuple to list, with new elements after each existing one

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

Question may be confusing, so here's an example:

I want to go from a tuple like `(a, b, c)` to a list of the form `[a, 1, b, 1, c, 1]`. What's the most Pythonic way to do this? I tried something like `[*(x, 1) for x in list]`, before realizing that you can't unpack in list comprehension. What's the best way to do this? I already searched for a while and couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Related: [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/4518341)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can "unpack" in a list comprehension, but not quite like that. Use another loop.

```
xs = (a, b, c)
[e for x in xs for e in (x, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> t = ('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((x, 1) for x in t))
['a', 1, 'b', 1, 'c', 1]
```

But personally I'd prefer the chained comprehension solution in [glitch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62976083/4518341)